How to get value from editableSelect() by jquery in asp.net c#
I am trying to get the id of selected list item (html-editableSelect), but in the place of select Id value I am getting undefined alert.
Here is my aspx code
<select id="cmb_year" runat="server" onselect="loadCounties()"></select>
<script>
    $('#<%=cmb_year.ClientID%>').editableSelect()
</script>

<script>
    function loadCounties() {
        alert($('#cmb_year').attr('value'));
    }
</script>

Here is my aspx.cs code
service.BindHTMLDropdownList(cmb_year, "tbl_year", "year", "Id", "order by Id desc");


Set clientidmode="static" for the cmb_year and in javascript address it as $('#cmb_year').

Interesting! This is a copy of the same question : How to get selected value from select list by javascript in asp.net c#

@ShahramAlemzadeh where I want to put clientidmode="static"?

clientidmode is an attribute for asp.net controls, so: <select id="cmb_year" runat="server" clientidmode="static" onselect="loadCounties()"></select>
